# Why I cannot write string to XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string array in my project and I want to append this to the xml.

The xml structure is:

```
 <data>
    <list>
      <item/>  <== array
    </list>
  </data>
```

and my array is :

```
string[] strArr = ["a", "b"];
```

my code

```
                XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"myxml.xml");
                foreach (var str in strArr )
                {
                    var list = xml.Root.Element("list");
                    list.Add(new XElement("item", str ));
                }
```

update question:

I also want to know why I cannot get the xml in string array..

```
           var strs= from elements in xml.Elements("data").Elements("list") select elements;

            foreach (var str in strs)
            {
                string item= id.Element("item").Value;
                strList.Add(item );

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initial XML file content:

```
<data>
   <list>

   </list>
</data>
```

Modify code as below

```
string[] strArr = {"a", "b"};
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"myxml.xml");
foreach (var str in strArr )
{
   var list = xml.Root.Element("list");
   list.Add(new XElement("item", str ));
}
xml.Save(@"myxml.xml");
```

You are missing `Save` function call.

For adding elements in string array:

```
var strs = from elements in xml.Root.Element("list").Elements("item") select elements;
foreach (var str in strs)
{
    string item = str.Element("item").Value;
    strList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: @MRfuxkYou for your edit ; you forgot the Root, `xml.Root.Elements //...` ; *(as a side note `from elements in source select elements` can just be `source`)*